# How to handle application specific logic in Asp.net Core 2.1 Angular template

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using this Angular Template of Asp.net Core 2.1. 
[Angular Template of Asp.net Core 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpce.jpg)

- Scenario is I am using above angular template.
- I am using OpenID connect IdentityServer4 Authentication using Implicit Flow.
- Suppose, Now I have one third party API to get the Products information. 
  https://Somethirdpartyapi.com/api/v1/Products
  But now I need to display the Products based on the User Roles. So, where I can do the Authorization?
- 1. When user gets logged in, I am getting access_token and I get the User Roles.
- 2. In Angular, I already written the Code to handle Role based authorization like If Role is of Normal user then Show Released Products. 
     If Role is “SpecialUser” then Show EarlyRelease products something like that.
- 3. If I directly use that third-party API in my Angular Code, then ANYONE can call that API using the Token directly and then can skip my Client-Side Authorization flow written in my Angular Code.
- 4. User can call my third-party API with the help of that token using Postman.
- 5. Here Third party API mean, I can’t add or modify that API.

**My question is How to handle application specific logic like role-based things.
I need to show the information of Products based on User Role and I cant put that logic to the Product API because I don’t have any control over it.**

Comment: Any idea/ any thoughts guys?

Comment: You can probably have your own api(wrapper around third party API) within project that basically calls the third party api. You can have control over what data you want to return and restrict user from accessing it directly by using the token.

Comment: @user2884707bond - Thank you so much for your reply. 
Yes, I am doing it the same now. I have Asp.net core 2.1 Angular code. I have configured Implicit Flow Authentication for OpenID Connect. 
Now As per your suggestion, My Angular App will talk to only my own api using the token which app gets it from Implicit Flow Authentication. 

So far so good. 
If we go with this approach, then Same token I can't pass it to thirdparty api. 
**Now How can I call that third party API?**
I found this article here - 
[link](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html)

Comment: Glad I could help!